# Machine learning algorithm to identify areas with down time

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, geolocation

I receive realtime geo-coordinates for vehicle stop-offs and I would like to identify location hotspots in the data to define geofences. I have tried using DBSCAN for this :

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics

# represent GPS points as (lat, lon)
coords = df_out.as_matrix(columns=['glat', 'glng'])
# eps is the max distance that points can be from each other to be considered in a cluster
# min_samples is the minimum cluster size (everything else is classified as noise)
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.01/6371, min_samples=35, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))
```

But it fails with clustering correctly and freezes every time I upload data with 500k+ rows

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to actually solve? I don't see a case for ML here; you already have your data and you can already define hotspots. Sure, they're time-varying, but what are you expecting ML to do here?

Comment: "and the more days I have the more these loading spots appear along the way and all the time I have to go to Google Maps, see what approximate coordinates of these spots are and then add them to conditions" I don't follow. Something about this makes me think you've gone on a tangent to the actual issue

Comment: @roganjosh I'm expecting ML to identify these hotspots without me saying which they are. Usually, I upload visualize my data in 3d Maps, then check where these spikes occur, I then take center of this area and assign "Loading" zone to it. I would like ML to cluster these zones for me

Comment: At least for my part, I'm getting distracted by the context. If I were you, I'd strip out the pictures, the backstory, and focus on just getting DBSCAN working. It's tempting to throw all the context in, but it just isn't necessary here; all you're looking to do is cluster locations. Provided that there is some (in this case, failing) thing to run, people here aren't much concerned by context

Comment: "I receive daily/hourly/realtime geo-coordinates for vehicle stop-offs and I would like to identify location hotspots in the data to define geofences. I have tried using DBSCAN for this <insert code block> but it fails with <insert exception or other issue>." Something like that

Comment: Lol, "daily/hourly/realtime" was for you to pick something appropriate :) You might need to tweek it a bit more to fit your actual case, I just gave a framework. Still, I think it's getting easier to understand the problem and it shows willingness to take on feedback